# strange behavior of numpy.asmatrix or matplotlib.pyplot.scatter

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter

I found a strange behavior of Python, numpy, or matplotlib.

Please execute following code with pylab on ipython:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.random as nr
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
>>> data = nr.rand(50, 2)
>>> mp.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])
>>> trans = np.asmatrix(data.T)
>>> mp.scatter(trans[0, :], trans[1, :])
>>> all(data == trans.T)
```

I expected two figures created by this code are exactly same,
but they look slightly different.
The last line of the code also implies they are exactly same.

What is the problem?

python 2.7.4, IPython 0.13.2, pylab 1.7.1, numpy 1.7.1, matplotlib 1.2.0

Comment: Where are the two figures? You are plotting over the same figure.

Comment: Also you *are* generating random data, so the figures will look different if you run it again without seeding...

Comment: Sorry, my point is not what you mention.
My point is not plotting same figure or random seed, but
scatter(data) and scatter(trans) is not same shape.

Comment: I couldn't recreate your error. Is this all the code?

Comment: You mean that you cannot see two figures?
I think you can see a figure at first scatter(), and then please close the figure window, then at next scatter() you can see another figure. My question is that these two figures should be same shape but they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `np.asmatrix()` just convert an iterable to a matrix, when applicable. So:

```
 trans = np.asmatrix(data.T)
 np.all( data == trans.T )
```

should always give `True`

The problem with the different plots is that in `matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter` the `ravel()` is executed in the `numpy.ma` (Masked Arrays) module. Here, despite `data==trans.T`, `np.ma.ravel(trans[0,:])` returns a matrix instead of a flattened array. To fix that you can call `np.ravel()`, that works for non-masked arrays. I opened [this issue in GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2138) to report this, which is possibly a bug...

The result will be:

```
fig, axs = mp.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True )

axs[0].scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])

trans = np.asmatrix(data.T)

axs[1].scatter( np.ravel(trans[0,:]), np.ravel(trans[1,:]) )

fig.tight_layout()
```

giving you this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I mean that, these two subfigures should be exactly same shape but they are not.

Comment: I have seen the issue in GitHub of this problem. I set myself to use numpy.array than numpy.matrix when I pass matrices to numpy's functions. However numpy.matrix is simple and useful when I want to multiply... Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: @keisuke you should keep using `np.ndarray` objects, and to multiply simply do `a.dot(b)`... the issue on GitHub is still opened...

Comment: To follow up, this has been (better) documented and will be in the 1.4.0 docs. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3394